# Getting total count of a another column using a specific day in a month?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

```
   VendorID tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime  passenger_count  PULocationID  DOLocationID  fare_amount
0       1.0  2020-01-01 00:28:15   2020-01-01 00:33:03              1.0           238           239          6.0
1       1.0  2020-01-01 00:35:39   2020-01-01 00:43:04              1.0           239           238          7.0
2       1.0  2020-01-01 00:47:41   2020-01-01 00:53:52              1.0           238           238          6.0
3       1.0  2020-01-01 00:55:23   2020-01-01 01:00:14              1.0           238           151          5.5
4       2.0  2020-01-01 00:01:58   2020-01-01 00:04:16              1.0           193           193          3.5
5       2.0  2020-01-01 00:09:44   2020-01-01 00:10:37              1.0             7           193          2.5
6       2.0  2020-01-01 00:39:25   2020-01-01 00:39:29              1.0           193           193          2.5
7       1.0  2020-01-01 00:29:01   2020-01-01 00:40:28              2.0           246            48          8.0
8       1.0  2020-01-01 00:55:11   2020-01-01 01:12:03              2.0           246            79         12.0
9       1.0  2020-01-01 00:37:15   2020-01-01 00:51:41              1.0           163           161          9.5
```

I have this data for  January 2020(spans for the whole month, this is just a snippet) ,I  want to answer a question like 'Saturday is the busiest day in terms of passenger pickups.'
How do I go about it?
the data type of column with labels 'tpep_pickup_datetime' and 'tpep_dropoff_datetime' are of object type.

Comment: I guess, you need to convert `tpep_pickup_datetime` to pandas `datetime` first. Then find  the `day_name` from the date time value. Group on the `day_name` and check the max `passenger_count`. That will be the busiest day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First data was changed for different datetimes in column `tpep_pickup_datetime` for better sample:

```
print (df)
   VendorID tpep_pickup_datetime tpep_dropoff_datetime  passenger_count  \
0       1.0  2020-01-01 00:28:15   2020-01-01 00:33:03              1.0   
1       1.0  2020-01-02 00:35:39   2020-01-01 00:43:04              1.0   
2       1.0  2020-01-02 00:47:41   2020-01-01 00:53:52              1.0   
3       1.0  2020-01-03 00:55:23   2020-01-01 01:00:14              1.0   
4       2.0  2020-01-03 00:01:58   2020-01-01 00:04:16              1.0   
5       2.0  2020-01-03 00:09:44   2020-01-01 00:10:37              1.0   
6       2.0  2020-01-04 00:39:25   2020-01-01 00:39:29              1.0   
7       1.0  2020-01-04 00:29:01   2020-01-01 00:40:28              2.0   
8       1.0  2020-01-04 00:55:11   2020-01-01 01:12:03              2.0   
9       1.0  2020-01-05 00:37:15   2020-01-01 00:51:41              1.0   

   PULocationID  DOLocationID  fare_amount  
0           238           239          6.0  
1           239           238          7.0  
2           238           238          6.0  
3           238           151          5.5  
4           193           193          3.5  
5             7           193          2.5  
6           193           193          2.5  
7           246            48          8.0  
8           246            79         12.0  
9           163           161          9.5
```

Convert column to datetimes, get names of day by [`Series.dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df['tpep_pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_pickup_datetime'])

df['day'] = df['tpep_pickup_datetime'].dt.day_name()

s = df.groupby('day')['passenger_count'].sum()
print (s)
day
Friday       3.0
Saturday     5.0
Sunday       1.0
Thursday     2.0
Wednesday    1.0
Name: passenger_count, dtype: float64
```

Then for index, here name of day of maximal value use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), for maximal value use `max`:

```
print (s.idxmax())
Saturday

print (s.max())
5.0
```

And if need both is possible use [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html):

```
print (s.agg(['idxmax','max']))
idxmax    Saturday
max              5
Name: passenger_count, dtype: object
```

Comment: How do I relate the number of passenger count with the passenger pickups (this is label PULocationID) or passenger drop off (DOLocationID)?

Comment: @waithira - Not easy understand, do you need `df.groupby(['day','PULocationID'])['passenger_count'].sum()` ? And then `print (s.idxmax()[0])`
 Or 
`print (s.groupby(level=1).idxmax())` ?

Comment: in the case of I want to answer this question,Tuesday is the busiest day in terms of passenger drop-offs.?

Comment: passenger_count is included plus a filter on the PULocationID

Comment: @waithira -  I think here is big problem with your data - all data are `2020-01-01` so how possible `Tuesday` ? Is possible change data - remove not important columns and change datetimes similar like in my answer with change `PULocationID`, `DOLocationID`? Because now it is all about guessing, what need (because data cannot verify)

Comment: I was the one who had not understood the question well ,I have understood what you had answered thanks